# confusion matrix and classification report of StratifiedKFold

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am using StratifiedKFold to checking the performance of my classifier. I have two classes and I trying to build Logistic Regression classier. 
Here is my code

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(x, y):
    x_train, x_test = x[train_index], x[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
    x_train = tfidf.fit_transform(x_train)
    x_test = tfidf.transform(x_test)

    clf =  LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced')
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)
    score = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    r.append(score)
    print(score)

print(np.mean(r))
```

I could just print the score of the performance but I couldn't figure out how to print the confusion matrix and classification report.If I just add print statement inside the loop,

```
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
```

it will print it 10 times, but I want to report and a matrix of the final performance of the classifier.

Any help about how to calculation the matrix and the report. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO; please post what you have tried so far and the *specific issues* you face - as is, you don't give any useful information even on very elementary stuff (e.g. how many classes?)

Comment: sorry for that, I will edit the post

Answer (score 1):

Cross validation is used to asses the performance of particular models or hyperparameters across different splits of a dataset. At the end you don't have a final performance per se, you have the individual performance of each split and the aggregated performance across splits. You could potentially use the tn, fn, fp, tp for each to create an aggregated precision, recall, sensitivity, etc... but then you could also just use the predefined functions for those metrics in sklearn and aggregate them at the end.

e.g.

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
accs, precs, recs = [], [], []
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(x, y):
    x_train, x_test = x[train_index], x[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
    x_train = tfidf.fit_transform(x_train)
    x_test = tfidf.transform(x_test)

    clf =  LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced')
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)
    acc = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    prec = precision_score(y_test, y_pred)
    rec = recall_score(y_test, y_pred)
    accs.append(acc)
    precs.append(prec)
    recs.append(rec)
    print(f'Accuracy: {acc}, Precision: {prec}, Recall: {rec}')

print(f'Mean Accuracy: {np.mean(accs)}, Mean Precision: {np.mean(precs)}, Mean Recall: {np.mean(recs)}')
```