# Creating confusion matrix with StratifiedKFold in Random Forest

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

Similar question but with different dataset
[confusion matrix and classification report of StratifiedKFold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55003149/confusion-matrix-and-classification-report-of-stratifiedkfold)

I'm trying to create a confusion matrix using Titanic data set. I followed [this](https://www.kaggle.com/gunesevitan/titanic-advanced-feature-engineering-tutorial) kaggle notebook and

there is this part to run `StratifiedKFold` with RandomForest part. I little bit modified to code to get confusion matrix. See **ADDED** line.

OTH, I do not understand how to split train and test data set works `StratifiedKfold`. Since in this notebook they already separated. I do not know where to get `y_test` to provide data to confusion matrix.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, classification_report
N = 2
oob = 0
probs = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(X_test), N * 2)), columns=['Fold_{}_Prob_{}'.format(i, j) for i in range(1, N + 1) for j in range(2)])
importances = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((X_train.shape[1], N)), columns=['Fold_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, N + 1)], index=df_all.columns)


fprs, tprs, scores, conf_matrix = [], [], [], []

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=N, random_state=N, shuffle=True)

for fold, (trn_idx, val_idx) in enumerate(skf.split(X_train, y_train), 1):
    print('Fold {}\n'.format(fold))
    
    # Fitting the model
    single_best_model.fit(X_train[trn_idx], y_train[trn_idx])
    
    #ADDED
    y_pred = single_best_model.predict(X_test)
    
    conf_matrix.append(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
   
    
    
    # Computing Train AUC score
    trn_fpr, trn_tpr, trn_thresholds = roc_curve(y_train[trn_idx], single_best_model.predict_proba(X_train[trn_idx])[:, 1])
    trn_auc_score = auc(trn_fpr, trn_tpr)
    # Computing Validation AUC score
    val_fpr, val_tpr, val_thresholds = roc_curve(y_train[val_idx], single_best_model.predict_proba(X_train[val_idx])[:, 1])
    val_auc_score = auc(val_fpr, val_tpr)  
      
    scores.append((trn_auc_score, val_auc_score))
    fprs.append(val_fpr)
    tprs.append(val_tpr)
    
    # X_test probabilities
    probs.loc[:, 'Fold_{}_Prob_0'.format(fold)] = single_best_model.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 0]
    probs.loc[:, 'Fold_{}_Prob_1'.format(fold)] = single_best_model.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
    importances.iloc[:, fold - 1] = single_best_model.feature_importances_
        
    oob += single_best_model.oob_score_ / N
    print('Fold {} OOB Score: {}\n'.format(fold, single_best_model.oob_score_))   
    
print('Average OOB Score: {}'.format(oob))
```

The first error I'm getting is that `y_test` and I don't know how this guy defined y_test. I cannot find it anywhere in the notebook.

After I got the `matrix` I want to get something like this

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/evaluating-a-random-forest-model-9d165595ad56

[image]

Comment: This depends on what exactly you want to score the model on, but I would suggest the `cross_val_predict` function to generate out-of-fold predictions.

Comment: @BenReiniger thanks. why we cannot use confusion matrix ?

Comment: You can. I'm saying that if you don't have/need a test set and are doing cross-validation (depending on why), use `cross_val_predict` to get the models' predictions for the confusion matrix.